# Free alternatives to Windows nap?

Tags: windows

[NAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Access_Protection) was depreciated in 2012R2 and now Microsoft says it is not even present in Win 10 Server. I read [this article](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/3-reasons-why-network-access-protection-being-phased-out) which explains NAP is not as relevant today as there are better technologies to accomplish NAC or BYOD policies.

For my own edification: **What are some popular free software based solutions people actually use?** Specifically the feature usually included in NAC solutions that puts a client on a remediation network so it can get updates or the install a NAC agent so its health can be checked.